# Python3.6 logging module: how to log to file the error which cause the application to terminate prematurely?

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, error-handling

The logging module does it's job to report things occurring before the application crash. But somehow it missed the most important part: it doesn't log the error that crash the app, which I find surprising (I'm a beginner).

I know I could print these errors using the `try except` statement. But it's a rather complicate step to merely print the error which crash the app (it requires to modifies the code).

I did spent few hours trying to understand the documentations, and quite a bunch of thread about it, but I did not find the basic answer of this basic question.

Is there a way to log these `NameError`, `SytaxError`, and any runtime error on a file.log?

Comment: It's not *surprising* as that's not its job.  Some years ago, though, I did write [a Python wrapper to make Python programs act more like Unix utilities](https://github.com/chris3torek/py-start), writing stack traces to "core dump" files. This could be adapted for similar use. See also commercial products like Rollbar.

Comment: @torek thanks for these infos and link! I understand from your answer that it would be difficult to log these errors. Sorry for the basic question, but why would it be difficult to log these errors? (I'm a beginner trying to understand how that works).

Comment: It's not so much a "would be difficult" case as "not the goal". My wrapper does not *use* the logging module, but using the logging module would be a reasonable thing for my wrapper to do. Essentially, we pick different "levels" or "domains" at/in which to solve problems, and the problem domain for logging is "how to get messages into persistent data stores", while the problem domain you're looking at—app-wide "catch a problem that's about to crash the app"—is quite separate. "Logging" might be just one of many actions you might take, at that point.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't have a clue of what you are talking about. I read several time your answer but without any luck. As I told you, I'm just  a beginner trying to understand how that works.

Comment: Analogies are always suspect, but try this analogy anyway. Imagine you're building a car. You can buy individual engine parts—valves, pistons, the block, crankshaft, and so on—or a fully assembled engine. The `logging` module is full of individual parts so that *you* can assemble a four cylinder engine, or a straight six, or a V8. It's not a pre-assembled engine or fully formed car; that's not its *job*; it's there to be used as *parts*. If you went to a parts company and asked them why they don't sell complete cars, what answer would you get?